# Why are the main characters of Amagi Brilliant Park named after singers?

Tags: amagi-brilliant-park

Is it there any particular reason why the main characters of Amagi Brilliant Park are named after rap singers?

To be precise:

- Kanie Seiya (可児江 **西**也) is named after [Kanye West](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanye_West)

  (西 means west)
- Latifa Fleuranza after [Queen Latifah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_Latifah)
- Sento Isuzu (千斗{せんと} いすず) after [50 Cent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/50_Cent).

  (Sento is homophone with Cent セント。 いすず can be rendered as **五十**鈴 in kanji where 五十 means 50)

So, I  guess there is a reason for this and I was wondering what it may be.

Comment: Also "Kurisu Takaya", who is presumably Chris Tucker.

Comment: Maybe KyoAni loves Western rap and hip hop.

Comment: KyoAni isn't the one that named the characters. The series is an adaptation of a light novel.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the author enjoys punny/goofy name schemes. The part-time workers hired by Kanie are named Eiko Adachi, Biino Bandou, and Shiina Chuujou-- A, B, and C. (More obvious in Japanese where their family names would be written first.)

And senshin is right-- Kurisu Takaya is a near-direct transliteration of "Chris Tucker". (Fun fact, a similar gag is used in Steins;Gate for the character Kurisu Makise; she often gets called "Christina"/Kurisu-tina.)